# What disk do virtual machines use in VMWare workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I use VMWare Workstation and keep my virtual machines on a separate physical disk, not my boot drive.  Does this mean that the VM's IO will be against that disk when it is running?

Comment: Nice one, thanks for the super swift responses guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All I/O in these virtual machines will be redirected by VMWare to the file that contains the virtual machine's disk. If that file is on secondary disk, then naturally all I/O will happen against that disk.

Note that this does **not** mean that I/O on the primary disk will not be impacted at all. Some I/O impact is system-wide (e.g. bus traffic, associated CPU-time, etc.)

Comment: right, just what I meant, in a clearer manner

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that the VM's IO will be against that disk when it is running?

A bulk of them will hit the disk dedicated to the VM, but your primary disk will still be accessed especially for swap access & MFT updates